# How to add a default post build action on every project created?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've figured out that it's quite simple to have an email sent when builds fail by editing the configuration settings of specific project builds by using the email-ext plugin. Is there someway that I could have this as a default setting for whenever new project builds are constructed? I don't want to have to manually set the post build action to have emails sent every time.

Is there a way to do this? Would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: Create a jenkins job which would act as a Template. Now use this template as a blueprint in creating new jobs similar to that.

To be precise, you can use jenkins api/cli in creating a new job from this template.

We have CI jobs which have/ need similar configuration, except branch name changes (which can parameterized and changed on the fly), we use above case 1.

Case 2: Write a groovy script which can update all jobs/selected jobs.

Case 3: Use [jenkins configuration slicing plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin). With this plugin, you can easily enable / disable / change / customize email section (and a lot more other actions) from jenkins manage (global section).